# OpenCV 3.0 install WITH_OPENCL_SVM=ON on Machine with OpenCL 1.1

Tags: c++, opencv, build, opencl

So I installed OpenCV WITH_OPENCL_SVM=ON thinking that I was going to eventually get a GPU with OpenCL 2.0 on it (currently only 1.1.)  However now when I try to run any programs with OpenCV I get an

> Error on line 2629 (ocl.cpp): CL_DEVICE_SVM_CAPABILITIES via clGetDeviceInfo failed: -30

I believe when I create a cv::UMat. The line of code in ocl.cpp is dependent on HAVE_OPENCL_SVM being defined, I assume it then does a check for the SVM capability and fails that check because I don't have 2.0.  I tried:

```
#undef HAVE_OPENCL_SVM
```

in my code and modifying cvconfig.h (honestly don't know how/when that file is referenced) so that it is not defined as well as un-defining it there again... and the error persists.

Thanks!

Comment: Exactly what do you expect this to do? SVM is a OpenCL2.0 feature (unless your implementation supports it via some backwards compatibility extension), so using it with OpenCL1.1 will "try to use a feature that doesn't exist/work", which is indeed likely to fail.

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping that I wouldn't have to completely remove and re-install OpenCV, is there a way to "turn it off" the option short of doing that?

Comment: Sorry, don't know much about OpenCV, and even less about how the installation works and what it changes....